# fetch the value of number of active threads in a process

Tags: unix, ps

I am trying to fetch the number of threads of a process in a UNIX using command line. After going through the man page of unix command, I learnt that following command:

```
ps -o nlwp <pid>
```

returns the number of threads spawned in a process.

Whenever i executed above command in unix, it returned:

```
NLWP
   7
```

Now, I want to neglect NLWP and a space before 7.

That is I am just interested in a value, as I will be using it in a script, that I am writing for unit testing?

Is it possible to fetch only value, and neglect everything(Title **NLWP**, space)?

Comment: can you reopen your recent question?  I understood what you were asking and was working on an answer, even though no one else seems to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the `--no-headers` option in `ps` to get rid of the headers.

In that case, use `awk` to just print the first value:

```
ps --no-headers -o nlwp <pid> | awk '{print $1}'
```

Or `tr` to remove the spaces:

```
ps --no-headers -o nlwp <pid> | tr -d ' '
```

---

If `--no-headers` is not supported in your `ps` version, either of these make it:

```
ps -o nlwp <pid> | awk 'END {print $1}'
ps -o nlwp <pid> | tail -1 | tr -d' '
```